# MDM mobile app recommended flow/strategy

Tags: identityserver4

I would like to be able to authenticate via OpenID/mobile app on a MDM enrolled device, without user having to login ( as with a classical hybrid pkce flow ),

I mean , the device is enroled on MDM so I would like to authenticate against identity server and find some way to used some mdm pushed infos on the device to be able to bypass the user interaction.

but I'm not able to find some advices or articles in order to be able to do that on a minimal safe way.

Is somebody maybe could give an advice or somewhere to look , I'm quite lost to be honest.

Thks !

Comment: Hi guys, no answer at all ?